Stripe Address Element Add Asterisks To Required
I'm using the AddressElement from Stripe in React/Next.
How can I customize the label for the input?
For example, if I want a * to show up for if it's required, how would I do that?
I tried looking at the Appearance API and tried setting some rules, but there's no content available for their CSS rules.

Stripe will show red borders for any required fields that are not filled out during submit. Unfortunately, there's not a way to add additional text (e.g. "*") or show that fields are required before the end-user attempts to fill them out or submit the form.

Thanks! Was hoping I was missing something, guess I'll be building my own component....
